# Passing an object from a tabbarController to its subviews

Tags: core-data

I am trying to pass a simple core data objects info from a tabBarController to its subviews so that they each reference a different attribute of that object.  As a newbie, I'm not sure even where to start.  It doesn't seem to be as simple as passing the data from one tableView to another...

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being very simple.  I was trying to call the object in the child views initWithNibName which doesn't work.  I ended up creating a setObject function and calling the properties I wanted in viewWillAppear.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

A `UITabBarController` should be handling other view controllers, not handling data objects. How does the tab bar controller get the object reference in the first place? And what is the object you're sharing?

Let each of your subordinate VC's keep a pointer to the object, and then they can each follow the appropriate keypath to get to the entities they're designed to handle.

Tim Roadley's book *Learning Core Data for iOS*, in chapters 5 and 6, shows how to pass an object from one view controller (a table view) to a detail view. It doesn't sound like that's what you're asking, but just in case...

---

In response to comment:

I'm looking at a tableview, tap a cell, and then a tab bar controller slides in? That's not the usual visual metaphor for a tab bar; it's meant for changing modes for the entire program. See the Music app for a typical example: songs, playlists, artists.

But if you really need to do it that way, try this (I'm assuming you're using storyboards):

- In `prepareForSegue:` in your tableview controller, tell the destination (tab bar controller) what object it's working with.
- In the tab bar controller's `-viewWillAppear`, tell each of its tabs about the attribute: `self.frobisherViewController.frobisher = self.myWidget.frobisher`.

You could instead tell each of the component tabs about the top level object: `self.frobisherViewController.widget = self.myWidget`. But I like the first approach better because there is less linkage. The `frobisherViewController` now would need to know about both widgets and frobishers.

Comment: I am using the tabBarController as a detail view of an object picked from a tableView Controller. Not sure if that makes sense, and as a total newby, i realize I may be breaking some cardinal rule by doing that. So it inherits the properties of the core data object I want to show in each of the tab child controllers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sharing the same object between (most of the) the view controllers of your tab bar controller, maybe the best architecture for this would be to have one central data object.

A typical pattern is a singleton, some kind of data manager that provides the object, but maybe that is overkill. Another is to keep references to all view controllers and update them one by one when something changes - also not very elegant.

What you really want is something like a global variable. You could (ab)use your app delegate (just give it a property that points to the object) or if you prefer even your tab bar controller (make a subclass, give it a property). In the latter case, every view controller could then get the object like this:

```
NSManagedObject *object = [(MyCustomTabBarController*)self.tabBarController object];
```

For example, you can check for changes and refresh your views in `viewWillAppear`.